# How to change default Heading names in QuillJS (react-js)?

Tags: javascript, quill, react-quill

I have my Quill text editor set up like this in the constructor:

```
this.modules = {
            toolbar: {
                container: [
                ...
                [{ 'header': [1, 2, false], 3 }],
                ...]
            }
        };
```

It produces a drop down menu with these names: 'Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Normal', 'Heading 3'.

I want to keep the values / functions attached to those names the same. I just want to change the names to: 'Title', 'Subheading', 'Paragraph', 'Small Paragraph'.

How would I change the names to 'Title', 'Subheading', 'Paragraph', 'Small Paragraph'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, header behaviour is somewhat unexpected. You can achieve the result you want in two possible ways. **The first approach** would be to configure the editor's toolbar using HTML, and add a few more details:

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  }
});
```

```css
#toolbar .ql-header {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="toolbar">
  <div class="ql-formats">
    <select class="ql-header">
      <option value="1">Title</option>
      <option value="2">Subheading</option>
      <option value="3">Small Paragraph</option>
      <option selected="selected">Normal text</option>
    </select>
    <button class="ql-clean"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="editor">
  <p>Try me...</p>
</div>
```

I must tell you that it is not possible to set the option false, or normal, or paragraph in the header. I already tried, and unfortunately, the desired result does not appear. And likewise, I have no way of telling you why. In case you want to find out the reason, I suggest you look at [header source code](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/formats/header.js).

Therefore, to remove the header formatting and leave the text as normal (as a simple paragraph), you can use the clean format, as shown in the previous example.

**A second approach** that could be used to solve your problem would be to create a new format. You could configure this new format to receive values, and behave in different ways according to the past value, which would even include removing the format itself if a false value was passed. There is an example of how to do this [here](https://github.com/loagit/Quill-Examples-and-FAQ#quill-project-001---hightlight). The highlight project (Nº 1) has everything you need.

**In summary**, the first approach uses two formats to do what you want. If that is not desired, I suggest you take the second approach. Even if it turns out to be a little more complex, it'll allow you to achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can change only CSS if want continue use modules and formats options and not raw HTML.

CSS mode:

```
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-item[data-value="1"]:before, .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-header .ql-picker-label[data-value="1"]:before {
    content: "<new-text-here>";
}
```

It's important to notice that each `data-value` is your value in header.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  }
});
```

```css
#toolbar .ql-header {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="toolbar">
  <div class="ql-formats">
    <select class="ql-header">
      <option value="1">Title</option>
      <option value="2">Subheading</option>
      <option value="3">Small Paragraph</option>
      <option selected="selected">Normal text</option>
    </select>
    <button class="ql-clean"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="editor">
  <p>Try me...</p>
</div>

****
```

****

---

> `jjj`

---

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.